# where is Safari's Reader code?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, code-analysis

Safari 5 has gotten a new feature: The Reader. It shows a simplified version of an article page with just the article itself (and not all the clutter around). It also merges multiple pages (if the article is split across multiple pages) to a single one.

This is an extremely useful feature and I would like to port it over to Chrome.

I was searching for Readers code in the WebKit trunk (e.g. http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/) but I couldn't find it.

Any hint where I can find it?

Comment: Safari != WebKit. It may use WebKit for rendering, and Apple may contribute a lot to the Project, but in the End Safari itself is still a closed source Application. So my guess is, that you'll have to reverse engineer it somehow, that means, see what it does and write your own code. Since I don't believe that Apple will give you theirs.

Comment: @Ivo: Have you downloaded the WebKit nightly build and compared it to Safari? I haven't seen any difference. It also contains the Reader I was talking about.

Comment: @Ivo: Out of curiosity, I have asked exactly that question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329405/what-are-the-differences-in-the-webkit-nightly-build-binary-and-in-the-safari-bin).

Comment: <s>Uh, mea culpa then, should have checked that before commenting, when it's in the nightly too, then it should definitely be somewhere on the trunk.</s>

Comment: OK, rechecked the whole thing, long time since I last downloaded a WebKit nightly. Even though you've downloaded the nightly of WebKit, you're still running it in Safari, am I right? If so, my initial comment still holds true, since Apple still can have code inside of Safari that's completely independent of WebKit.

Comment: The Manbolo blog's instructions to get this code still work: http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/03/18/safari-reader-source-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI-level features are generally part of the Safari codebase, which as Ivo said is not open-source. The WebKit nightly builds aren't open-source either, they are essentially versions of Safari that use an embedded, trunk copy of the engine instead of the one that shipped with the OS.

Answer (score 5):

Safari Reader borrows from the Readability project, according to an article in the register.  Readability implements a similar user experience, but does so in a cross browser fashion (using bookmarklets)

The project site is probably a good place to start:

http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/

I hope this helps!

BTW - I had links to several sites, including the demo site, the original artcile in the register, but stackoverflow won't let n00bs post more than one link.  I will edit to add those once I have some rep!

Comment: Have read already that it is based on this. Although Safaris Reader seems to be a bit extended (like converting multiple pages into a single one -- I think Readability can not do this). But good to have this link here, thanks!

Comment: Is there a version of Readability that is not dependent on WebKit?  It seems that WebKit (on Mac OS X) insists on being run in the main thread, thus cannot be used for heavy HTML parsing in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where safari's webreader code is. but there is a tool called [boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) that does something very similar

Answer (score 1):

A good review on similar tools available is given on Tomaz Kovacic's blog: http://tomazkovacic.com/blog/122/evaluating-text-extraction-algorithms/

It contains comparison of text extraction tools (including boilerpipe, reaability and several others) on two sets of articles. Also there is a feature wise comparison in other article on the same blog.